# card border is not gone - flutter

Tags: flutter

how to remove the border of the card
i have used the borderonforegound to false but not taking effect

```
 Widget createViewItem(Services service, BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
        child: ListTile(
        title: new Card(
            borderOnForeground: false,
          //elevation: 8.0,
          child: new Container(
              color: Colors.grey[50],
              width: 100,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                _getListTile(service.customerName, service.issue, service.recievedTime)
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change elevation property to 0.

```
Card(
  elevation: 0,
  child: ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
Card(
  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.zero,
  ),
  elevation: ...
  child: ...
);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score 0):

better choice:

```
Card(
elevation: 0,
margin: const EdgeInsets.all(0),...}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Card(
shape: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(
             color: Colors.grey.shade100,
           ),
        ),
child: ....
),
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).